# Highlight only one of few sections with the same class

Tags: jquery, html, css

When user clicks on a radio button in a section, **the section should be highlighted** (background-color).

But when he **clicks on a radio in another section,** the old highlighted one should go back to the default non-highlighting color.

Here is what I have - `http://jsfiddle.net/VaclavZeman/Xd596/`

I'm pretty sure It's possible through jQuery but since I'm not very good at it, I have no idea how.

This is some draft I've done but it's not working in JSFiddle.

```
$(".reference").click(function(){
  $(this).addClass("selected");
});
```

**How do I highlight just one of sections? Also how to remove the class in old section if user clicks on another section (.reference)?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First use `.removeClass()` for the class & then use `$(this).addClass()`

http://jsfiddle.net/Xd596/3/

```
$(".reference").click(function () {
    $(".reference").removeClass("selected");
    $(this).addClass("selected");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".radio").click(function(){
  $('.reference').removeClass('selected');
  $(this).closest('.reference').addClass("selected");
});
```

`.radio` are your checkboxes

`closest('.reference')` will match the closest `section` tag with `class="reference"`

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v9DQe/1/